# Change the background color in a twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When creating a modal in twitter bootstrap, is there any way to change the background color?  Remove the shading entirely?

NB: For removing shading, this *doesn't* work, because it also changes the click behavior.  (I still want to be able to click outside the modal to close it.)

```
$("#myModal").modal({
  backdrop: false
});
```

Comment: Note, from a usability perspective, retaining the click to dismiss behavior without any visual feedback at all (e.g. removing the shading entirely) is a pretty poor experience. There's nothing to indicate to the user that their click in the background is "safe" and won't go through to the control underneath. There's also nothing to indicate to the user that they _can_ click in the background to dismiss the modal in the first place.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

To change the color via:

### CSS

Put these styles in your stylesheet after the bootstrap styles:

```
.modal-backdrop {
   background-color: red;
}
```

### Less

Changes the bootstrap-variables to:

```
@modal-backdrop-bg:           red;
```

[Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L595)

### Sass

Changes the bootstrap-variables to:

```
$modal-backdrop-bg:           red;
```

[Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L603)

### Bootstrap-Customizer

Change `@modal-backdrop-bg` to your desired color:

[getbootstrap.com/customize/](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#modals)

---

You can also remove the backdrop via Javascript or by setting the color to `transparent`.

Comment: no it should also work with sass or none of it.
just be shure that you put these lines after the bootstrap.css. Did you try it???

Comment: Tried it but made a mistake the first time around.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: You just have to include the bootstrap.css before your css file and override the required classes to theme the modal the way you want.  That is the whole point of css...its cascading.

Comment: To find out which bootstrap class to modify, you can open Inspect Element. I am new to bootstrap and didn't find a good resource to find out all of the details about the bootstrap classes and where they are used.

Comment: I used a quick inline style on the modal-content object: 
     style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px;"

Answer (score 13):

If you want to change the background color of the backdrop for a specific modal, you can access the backdrop element in this way:

```
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').$backdrop
```

Then you can change any css property via .css jquery function. In particular, with background:

```
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').$backdrop.css('background-color','orange')
```

Note that $('#myModal') has to be initialized, otherwise $backdrop is going to be null. Same applies to  bs.modal data element.

Comment: This works perfectly for targeting a specific modal. And it seems that the initialization happens quickly enough that it works to put this line directly after `$('#myModal').modal();` (if not, this would have to be wrapped in an event listener for #myModal's 'shown' event). Note that instead of putting the css styles directly in javascript, you can use `$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').$backdrop.addClass('myModal-backdrop');` as @Simon-Bengtsson shows in his answer.

Comment: $backdrop is now undefined.

Comment: also _backdrop is null

Answer (score 7):

**CSS**

If this doesn't work:

```
.modal-backdrop {
   background-color: red;
}
```

try this:

```
.modal { 
   background-color: red !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

remove bootstrap modal background try this one

```
.modal-backdrop {
   background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It gets a little bit more complicated if you want to add the background to a specific modal. One way of solving that is to add and call something like this function instead of showing the modal directly:

```
function showModal(selector) {
    $(selector).modal('show');
    $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('background-backdrop');
}
```

Any css can then be applied to the `background-backdrop` class.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following CSS;

```
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content{  background-color: #d4c484; }

<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
...
...
```

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap 4 you may have to use `.modal-backdrop.show` and play around with `!important` flag on both `background-color` and `opacity`.

E.g.

```
.modal-backdrop.show {
   background-color: #f00;
   opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove shading for only one type of modal windows, you can simply add ID to your modal window

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">...</div>
```

and in you css file add the following

```
#myModal .modal-backdrop {background-color: transparent;}
```

If you need to remove shading for all modal windows, just skip the step with assigning ID.

Comment: I tried this first and it doesn't work at all. It seems bootstrap puts the .modal-backdrop element in an entirely separate place in the DOM, not nested within the #myModal element. So the id #myModal has nothing to do with the .modal-backdrop and the CSS style is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I used couple of hours trying to figure how to remove background from launched modal, so far tried

```
.modal-backdrop {    background: none; }
```

Didn't work
even I have tried to work with javascript like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">   
 $('#modal-id').on('shown.bs.modal',  function () {
       $(".modal-backdrop.in").hide();     })
</script>
```

Also didn't work either.
I just added

```
data-backdrop="false"
```

to

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="false">......</div>
```

And Applying css CLASS

```
.modal {     background-color: transparent !important;  }
```

Now its working like a charm
This worked with Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

For Angular(7+) Project:

```
::ng-deep .modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
```

Otherwise you can use:

```
.modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When modal appears, it will trigger event `show.bs.modal` before appearing. I tried at `Safari 13.1.2` on `MacOS 10.15.6`. When `show.bs.modal` event triggered, the `.modal-backgrop` is not inserted into `body` yet.

So, I give up to `addClass`, and `removeClass` to `.modal-backdrop` dynamically.

After viewing a lot articles on the Internet, I found [a code snippet](https://www.codeply.com/p/5kNp3hxsVW). It `addClass` and `removeClass` to the `body`, which is the parent of `.modal-backdrop`, when `show.bs.modal` and `hide.bs.modal`  events triggered.

ps: I use [Bootstrap 4.5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/).

### CSS

```
// In order to addClass/removeClass on the `body`. The parent of `.modal-backdrop`
.no-modal-bg .modal-backdrop {
    background: none;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$('#myModalId').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
     $('body').addClass('no-modal-bg');
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
     // 'hide.bs.modal' or 'hidden.bs.modal', depends on your needs.
     $('body').removeClass('no-modal-bg');
});
```

#### References

1. [The code snippet after google](https://www.codeply.com/p/5kNp3hxsVW)
2. [Bootstrap 4.5, modal, #events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#events)
3. [Bootstrap 4.5 documents](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.modal-backdrop').css('background', '#00000073');
});
```