# Remove modal property from Bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can you manipulate the modal dialog for bootstrap not to show it as modal window without the gray overlay.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/Gbm89/14/ has a working example. All you have to do is add this line of css

```
.modal-backdrop {background: none;}
```

2) After modal initiation

```
$('#XXX').modal({show:true});
```

just trigger the code below

```
$('.modal-backdrop').removeClass("modal-backdrop");
```

3) add **data-backdrop="false"** to  and Bootstrap will do the rest.

Example:`<div class="modal" id="genericModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myModal").modal({
  backdrop: none;
});
```

Refer this discussion : [Change the background color in a twitter bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585689/change-the-background-color-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with css,

```
#myModal .modal-backdrop {background-color: transparent;}
```

Or also with jquery,

```js
$("#myModal").modal({
  backdrop: none;
});
```