# Form validation using javascript and BootstrapDialog

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-dialog

I'm trying to do form validation by using javascript, however, I think there are some issues for the name field.

Whenever I enter any value for name field, it will automatically skip other validation and direct me to index.php.

Another scenario is after I filled in all except name field, it will it will automatically skip other validation and direct me to index.php.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585689/change-the-background-color-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal 
http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

-->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href- "css/trying.css" >

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>



<script>

function showError(message) {

  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Attention',
    message: message,
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
    buttons: [{
      label: 'Ok',
      cssClass: 'btn-default',
      action: function(dialog) {
        dialog.close();
      }
    }]
  });

  return false;
}



function validationFunction($msg){
    var list = document.createElement('ul');
    for(var i = 0; i < $msg.length; i++) {
         var item = document.createElement('li');
         item.appendChild(document.createTextNode($msg[i]));
         list.appendChild(item);    
    }

    showError($msg);
    return false;
}


function validateForm(form) {

    var RE_NAME = /^[A-Z a-z]+$/;
    var RE_EMAIL = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/;
    var RE_PASSWORD = /^[\S]{6,20}$/
    var errors = [];

    var name = form.reg_full_name.value;
    var email = form.reg_email.value;
    var password = form.reg_password.value;
    var confirmPass = form.reg_confirmpass.value;
    //Name Validation
    if (name == "") {
        errors.push("Please enter your full name");
    }
    else if (!RE_NAME.test(x)){
        errors.push( "Please enter valid  name");

    }

    //Email Validation
    if (!RE_EMAIL.test(email)){
        errors.push("Please enter a valid Email");
    }


    //Password Validation
    if (password =="" || confirmPass =="" ){
        errors.push( "Password and Comfirmation Password required");
    }

    else if (!RE_PASSWORD.test(password)){
        errors.push("Please a enter a password 6 - 20 characters in length");
    }

    else if (password!= confirmPass){
        errors.push("Your password and confirmation password do not match");
    }



    //If more than 1 error
    if (errors.length > 1) {
        validationFunction(errors);
        alert(errors);
        return false;
    }



}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action=""
onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post">

Name: <input type="text" name="reg_full_name"><br><br>
Email: <input type="email" name="reg_email"><br><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="reg_password"><br><br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="reg_confirmpass"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, everyone. I've found the problem. 
Is my careless mistake, I've accidentally typed the wrong variable at this line which causes my whole validation

> !RE_NAME.test(x)

The problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The array "errors" doesn't get populated with the correct values.

The correct way to do this would be:

```
errors.push("Please enter your full name");
```

Then your errors array gets a new entry "Please enter your full name", which has an index of 0. The array now also has a length of 1. So you would need to adjust the block where you ask if there is more than one error to:

```
if (errors.length > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. :)
I thought errors.length is the array size. If only got 1 error, it will directly skip the if statement?

Comment: You are right, .length is the size of the array, more  exactly, the number of items there are inside of the array.
.length itself is not an array, so it doesn't begin with 0 if there is one item inside.

So if you want the validation to only show errors if there are more than 1 errors, like the comment says, then you need to say:

   if(errors.length>1){...} 
If there is only one error (or no error at all), then the code inside the brackets will not execute.