# Simple HTML Lightbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, thumbnails

I have created a simple lightbox:

```
<div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
  <a href="CoupleFull.jpg" data-title="Hi" data-lightbox=  class="d-block 
   mb-4 h-100">
  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="Couple.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the full size photo pops up it has a dark background behind it. I would like to change the color. How would I do that?

An additional piece of info about my code:

I used the Bootstrap thumbnail gallery template from this page:
https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-thumbnail-gallery/

And I then added the lightbox details.

Answer (score 0):

Code needs more clarity, which library you are using for lightbox as the build given by you doesn't have lightbox implemented

But if you are using bootstrap modal for displaying you're images. Try finding out `modal-backdrop` class in you build and overwrite it with your `background-color`.

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: red;
}

// change background-color property as per your design


//Change the opacity of backdrop

.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

References

1. https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7XVM2 (try here)
2. [Change the background color in a twitter bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585689/change-the-background-color-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal)