# Add a class or remove when another element contains specific class not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have a bootsstrap 5.2 modal and I wanna apply a background behind it when the modal is open, but I can't make it work.

This is the structure:

```
// index.html

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
    ...
  </a>
  <div id="background-opacity"></div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="modalToggle"> < This toggles the class "show"
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

```
// index.js

const backgroundChange = document.getElementById('background-opacity');
const modalToggle = document.getElementById('modalToggle');

// function toggleClass() {

//  if (modalToggle.classList.contains('.show')) {
//      backgroundChange.classList.add('.background-focus');
//      console.log('tem');
//  } else {
//      backgroundChange.classList.remove('.background-focus');
//  }
// }
// toggleClass();

modalToggle.classList.contains('show') ?
 backgroundChange.classList.add('background-focus') 
 : backgroundChange.classList.remove('background-focus')
```

I tried the two above on index.js, but the class "background-focus" is not being added to the div when the modal is open (when the class 'show' is added to it).

What am I doing wrong?

(Should anyone recommend jQuery, I don't know how to use it)

Comment: Just use CSS. you can add whatever you'd like to the `.modal-backdrop` class. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586158/9898651

Comment: Oh! That's pretty handy, which tag takes the class though? it is messing with the modal

Comment: It's added for you when bootstrap opens the modal, no need to add it to anything.